# n combinations in a population of x, the probability of covering all combinations when sampling z individuals

Tags: random, sampling

In a population of x objects, where n different types of objects exist, how is the probability of covering all n types when randomly sampling y objects estimated? What I'm interested in mostly is that I assume it increases non-linearly and that at some multiple of n, enough objects have been sampled to satisfy some desired probability.

Comment: This is the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Thank you. This was why I asked, since someone likely knew the exact way to learn more about it. So, basically n*(ln(n)+0.577) (if the population x is assumed to be infinite, I guess is the assumption in most descriptions of Coupon Collectors Problem. ) In the context I'm looking at, the population is a trillion, and the objects are 100, so I guess it behaves like infinity (not sure at what population size x it starts behaving infinite enough. ) So for n = 100, 100*(ln(100)+0.577) = 518. I guess Coupon Collectors Problem is probalistically 100% at n*Hn.

Comment: This is great, because it fits the context I'm looking at. I'd like the total objects picked to get all objects to be quite low, and n*Hn seems quite low to me.

Comment: here's why I asked if you're interested. https://www.scribd.com/document/495295168/Are-Self-recognizing-Thymus-Lymphocytes-More-Central-Than-People-Consider. principle of exlusion for adaptive immune system makes it 10^8 times more efficient (10^-3 probability of bumping into antigen vs 10^-11 probablity). thanks for pointing me to coupon collector problem, peace